# Random permutation with defined order of last occurrences

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, complexity

This Python function takes two arguments:

- `chr_list` which is a mutable sequence of characters `c`
- `chr_counts` which maps to each character `c` the number of occurrences `n`

For each character `c` in `chr_list`, it inserts this character into the list before its last occurrence `n-1` times, where `n` equals `chr_counts[c]`. The resulting list contains `chr_counts[c]` occurrences of each character `c`, and the order of *last occurrences* is preserved.

```
def insert_repetitions_before(chr_list, chr_counts):

  for c, num_occurences in chr_counts.items():
    num_repeats = num_occurences - 1
    orig_pos_last = chr_list.index(c)

    for curr_pos_last in range(orig_pos_last, orig_pos_last+num_repeats):
      random_pos_before_last = random.randint(0, curr_pos_last)
      chr_list.insert(random_pos_before_last, c)
```

**Example output:**

```
chr_list = ['c','o','d','e']
chr_counts = {'c': 3, 'o': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 2}
>>> insert_repetitions_before(chr_list, chr_counts)
>>> chr_list
['c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'o', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to make it more efficient. Currently its time complexity is *`O(n*m)`*, *`n`* being the number of distinct characters and *`m`* the average number repetitions. Perhaps something like `random.shuffle` on a list containing all characters with repetitions, followed by some reordering?

---

(I'm not sure whether this is the right site to ask, since this question isn't quite specific to Python. Maybe I'll move it to CS.)

Comment: So `chr_list` contains exactly the keys of `chr_counts` exactly once each?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, and each value in `chr_counts` is at least 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make it more efficient. Currently its time complexity is *`O(n*m)`*, *`n`* being the number of distinct characters and *`m`* the average number repetitions.

There are two important errors there. Firstly, the time complexity of the given code is worse than stated. Secondly, the stated complexity is optimal.

Taking those in reverse order: the stated complexity is optimal because the number of items which must be inserted into `chr_list` is \$\Theta(mn)\$, and no matter how you arrange things each insertion will take \$\Omega(1)\$ time.

However, the given code does insertions at random, and an insertion into a random position in a list takes \$\Theta(\textrm{len})\$ time, so the overall complexity of the given code should be \$\Theta(m^2 n^2)\$.

---

How to achieve optimal asymptotic performance? You need to arrange for the insertions to be done in order. I think that probably requires some additional datastructures. The simplest approach conceptually is to have an array (or a list in Python terms) to store the characters in their final positions and a datastructure of unassigned indexes which allows fast selection of the maximum element and a random element. In Pythonesque pseudocode:

```
tmpList = [None] * sum(chr_counts)
unassigned = new Datastructure(sum(chr_counts))
for c in reverse(chr_list):
  tmpList[unassigned.removeMax()] = c
  for i in 1 to chr_counts[c] - 1:
    tmpList[unassigned.removeRandom()] = c
copy tmpList to chr_list
```

The best implementation I've thought of so far for the datastructure of unassigned indexes combines a linked list for fast implementation of `max` with an array for fast implementation of `random`. I'm not familiar with Python's OO syntax, so this is again pseudocode:

```
class LinkedListNode:
  LinkedListNode prev
  LinkedListNode next
  int arrayIdx
  int value

class Datastructure:
  LinkedListNode[] array
  LinkedListNode sentinel = new LinkedListNode

  init(len):
    array = []
    for i in range(len):
      array[i] = new LinkedListNode { arrayIdx = i, value = i }
    for i in range(len-1):
      array[i].next = array[i+1]
      array[i+1].prev = array[i-1]
    sentinel.next = array[0]
    sentinel.prev = array[len-1]
    sentinel.next.prev = sentinel
    sentinel.prev.next = sentinel

  removeMax():
    return removeNode(sentinel.prev)

  removeRandom(rnd):
    randIdx = rnd.randint(0, len(array))
    return removeNode(array[randIdx])

  removeNode(node):
    # Remove from linked list
    node.next.prev = node.prev
    node.prev.next = node.next
    # Remove from array
    array[node.arrayIdx] = array[-1]
    array[node.arrayIdx].arrayIdx = node.arrayIdx
    del array[-1]

    return node.value
```

Note: I don't really think `Datastructure` is a good name, but it's not an easy class to name so I'm using it as a placeholder instead of `Foo`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `max(unassigned)` would be unnecessary if `unassigned` was ordered (ie. a list, not a set). Then you can just pick the last element. Also, `unassigned.remove` is linear-time operation with respect to size of `unassigned`. If you use a list, then it's just `tmpList[unassigned.pop(-1)] = c`. Either way, it's significantly faster than the original version. I might post a version with the efficient implementation of `random` you mentioned.

Comment: @kyrill, I don't think that either `list` or `set` have the desired performance, which is for `max`, `random`, and `remove` to all be constant time. That's why I suggested a composite data structure. To expand slightly, the linked list would be ordered (which is why `max` is fast) but the array would start ordered and become unordered (fast deletion by swapping the deleted element to the end). I also fudged the `remove` a bit: really `max` and `random` would have to return more complicated elements than just the index so that you can do that swap to the end without first searching for the node

Comment: I gave it some thought and it would be possible but ugly. You would need two arrays with three doubly-linked lists upon them to make it linear-time. One array will hold indices in order, a linked list will link these indices both ways to allow for quick deletions and `max`. Then a randomly shuffled array with indices and a linked list for this array (again quick deletions and `random`). Finally a linked list connecting these two arrays, to allow for quick deletions from `max` array when an index is picked from the `random` array and vice versa. There must be a nicer way to do it...

Comment: Actually the structure connecting the `max` and `random` arrays would not be a doubly-linked list but two maps (dictionaries). It would be nicer if implemented in OO-style, but arguably less efficient, especially since it's an interpreted language.

Comment: @kyrill, that's overkill. One array whose elements are the linked list nodes, and each node contains prev and next pointers, its index in the array, and the value (which here is an unassigned index in the permutation).

Comment: How would `random` work then? And why put node's index in array into the node itself? Is it because the array will be shuffled? Then how do you build the linked list?

Comment: @kyrill, updated with more pseudocode. The reason for putting the node's info into the node itself rather than using a dictionary is that the node exists purely for the purposes of this datastructure, so we can do so without harming other code, and we save the overhead of a dictionary.

Comment: Very well. Just correct `array[(i+1) % len]` to `array[i+1]` and `array[(i-1) % len]` to `array[i]`.

Comment: Hah, yes. Missed that when I refactored.